# Emulate MVC 6 Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, content-negotiation

I'd like to keep my code compact and concise, so I'd like to emulate the MVC 6 Controller class instead of maintaining a separate Controller and ApiController. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227624/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-json-or-partial-html) gets pretty close, but I'd like to remove the JSON assumption and support content negotiation. (Admittedly, I'll most likely use it only for the JSON functionality, but I like being flexible.)

Can anyone provide a simple example of an MVC 5 Controller with a method supporting content negotiation that could be called from AJAX? Optionally, an explanation of the sample would also be appreciated.

Comment: I've used Restfulie to do ConnNeg in MVC since MVC 3 or 4. https://github.com/mauricioaniche/restfulie.net otherwise you can just roll your own ActionFilter to do it

Comment: We ended up using AngularJS which took the MVC controller logic client side. Everything else was refactored into a separate Web API project.

Comment: I like to try to keep my stack unified as much as possible. Unless it's inherently different like SignalR since there's no way to do that with anything MVC provides