# MVC 4 return JSON as ActionResult

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, asp.net-apicontroller

i'm trying to get my apicontroller to work. But somehow i cannot return `Json()`.

**Here's the error message from the compiler:**

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<>'
>   to
>   'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'   Opten.Polyglott.Web D:\Development\git\Opten.Polyglott\src\Opten.Polyglott.Web\Controllers\NewsletterApiController.cs

I cannot explain why it cannot convert the `Json()` to the `ActionResult` even the `Json()`inherits `ActionResult`.

**Here's my controller:**

```
using MailChimp;
using MailChimp.Helper;
using Opten.Polyglott.Web.Models;
using Opten.Umbraco.Common.Extensions;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Core.Logging;
using Umbraco.Web.WebApi;

namespace Opten.Polyglott.Web.Controllers
{
    public class NewsletterApiController : UmbracoApiController
    {
        public ActionResult Subscribe(Newsletter newsletter)
        {
            bool isSuccessful = false;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                isSuccessful = SubscribeEmail(newsletter.Email);
            }

            return Json(new { isSuccess = isSuccessful });
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: your method is return json object of a certain type but your return type is of jsonresult. i think it's expecting a type there

Comment: @user1490835 what is the difference between my code and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227624/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-json-or-partial-html

Comment: System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult is the one you want. I'm not sure why "JSON" is mapping to System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult.

You can make it explicit:

   return System.Web.Mvc.Json(new { isSuccess = isSuccessful });

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is within the usings as the `UmbracoApiController` most likely inherits from `ApiController (from System.Web.Http)` not `Controller (from System.Web.Mvc)` and thus they have different dependencies. To fix your problem first remove the

`using System.Web.Mvc;`

and put the

`using System.Web.Http;`

as for the return in this case that would be `IHttpActionResult` so you would have something as follows:

```
using MailChimp;
using MailChimp.Helper;
using Opten.Polyglott.Web.Models;
using Opten.Umbraco.Common.Extensions;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Http;
using Umbraco.Core.Logging;
using Umbraco.Web.WebApi;

namespace Opten.Polyglott.Web.Controllers
{
    public class NewsletterApiController : UmbracoApiController
    {
        public IHttpActionResult Subscribe(Newsletter newsletter)
        {
            bool isSuccessful = false;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                isSuccessful = SubscribeEmail(newsletter.Email);
            }

            return Json(new { isSuccess = isSuccessful });
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Your explanation about ApiController (not Controller) helped me understand why all my responses automatically became JSON, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

It seems your Json is using class in System.Web.Http, not in System.Web.Mvc. In this case, you can use this code:

```
return new JsonResult{ isSuccess = isSuccessful };
```

Answer (score 1):

When using ActionResult using `Response.StatusCode` is a good practice:

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod()
{
    try
    {
        // ...
        // doing something here...
        // ...

        // success:
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return Json(new { responseText = "OK" });
    }
    catch
    {
        // error:
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(new { responseText = "ERROR" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in your WebApiConfig.cs file:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```