# Trying to return custom api response in a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I am getting an error whenever I try to call a custom api function in c# asp.net core.
The Error code I am getting

> Cannot implicitly convert type MnrtPortal.Helpers.CustomApiResponse to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult an explicit conversion exists.

```
 [Route("api/User")]
        public IActionResult User()
        {
            var user = new
            {
                Name = "Joshua",
                Age = 40
            };
            // return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
            return CustomApiResponse.Create(200,user,"success");
        }
```

Comment: What is `CustomApiResponse` ?

Comment: It is a custom function that I have defined to handle my api responses

Comment: Is that class which has a Create method ? What does that do ? You need to share that!

Comment: You should return an `IActionResult`

Comment: Your `CustomApiResponse.Create` returns `CustomApiResponse` object.But your action method signature is defined as `IActionResult`. Change it to `public CustomApiResponse User()`

Comment: There are plenty of posts on returning custom results from MVC controllers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227624/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-json-or-partial-html as well as plenty of posts explaining conversion error... Could you please clarify what type of new information you are looking for in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CustomApiResponse` doesn't implement `IActionResult`, so you cannot return it directly in a method that returns `IActionResult`. Pretty straight-forward.

You can either change the return type of the action to `CustomApiResponse`, which should trigger the default serializer (JSON) and cause a `JsonResult` to be created from that. Or you can simply wrap your object in an `OkObjectResult` which will have the same effect.

```
return Ok(CustomApiResponse.Create(200,user,"success"));
```

Finally, you can explicitly return a `JsonResult` if you prefer via:

```
return Json(CustomApiResponse.Create(200,user,"success"));
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but now I need additional help to pass the status code

Comment: Because your method takes `HttpStatusCode` enum, not an int (which is what you are passing). Replace 200 with `HttpStatusCode.OK`. But i strongly suggest you refresh your basic C# knowledge about classes,methods types etc before trying to build anything.