# how to get value of input tag in Javasctipt

Tags: javascript, html

This input tag always gives null value, what is problem with this code

Input tag (HTML)::

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Try..." id="myInput">
<form class="mb-3" id='form-wrapper' >
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

javascript::

```
let form = document.getElementById('form-wrapper')
var title = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     console.log(title)
})
```

Comment: The `<form>` should start before the `input type="text"` element.

Comment: Tried that but didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are getting the `title` before entering any value in the `input`, if you get the value inside `submit` handler then you will get the value:

```js
let form = document.getElementById('form-wrapper')
// var title = document.getElementById("myInput").value; // <-- value is not set

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    var title = document.getElementById("myInput").value; // <-- value is set 
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(title)
})
```

```html
<form class="mb-3" id='form-wrapper'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Try..." id="myInput">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

*P.S. I assume you want the `input` inside the `form`.*

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get the value entered in the form on submitting.

You can add a `name` attribute to your`input` tag like so:`<input name="title" id="my_input">` then in the javascript file you can write this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e)){
   e.preventDefault();
   let formdata = $(this).serialze();
   console.log(formdata.title);

}
```

Wrap the input with the form tag...your inputs must be between the form tag.
The line `let formdata = $(this).serialze();` takes the values with the `name` atttribute and stores it in the variable formdata

Comment: Serializing a form gets the value of all the inputs inside the form, OP is asking about getting value of a specific input.